# Can't get GLSL Shaders in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I've been developing opengl on this machine for a while now, and suddenly, GLEW reports i don't have the extensions needed to get opengl glsl running, even though it works in other projects. The funny part is, i even get

```
OpenGL Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL Renderer: GeForce 610M/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL Version: 3.3.0

OpenGL 2.0 is available!
[FAILED] OpenGL Shading Language is not available...
```

I use glsllib 0.9.4 to load the extensions, which in turn uses GLEW. My code is as follows:

```
bool Jogo::init() {
    if(glfwInit() != GL_TRUE) return false;

    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_FSAA_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_WINDOW_NO_RESIZE, GL_TRUE);

    if(glfwOpenWindow(1024, 768, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, GLFW_WINDOW) != GL_TRUE) return false;

    glewExperimental = true;
    if(initGLExtensions() != true) return false;

    glm::mat4 matrizModel = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    glm::mat4 matrizView = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0, 0, 3), glm::vec3(0, 0, 0), glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
    glm::mat4 matrizProjecao = glm::perspective(45.0f, 9.0f/16.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

    m_matrizMVP = matrizProjecao * matrizView * matrizModel;

    m_shader = m_gerenciadorShader.loadfromFile("vshader.glsl", "fshader.glsl");
    char *x = m_shader->getLinkerLog();

    m_shader->setUniformMatrix4fv("mvp", 1, GL_FALSE, &(m_matrizMVP[0][0]));

    m_world = new World();

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.2f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
    glClearDepth(0.0f);

    return true;
}
```

glsllib's code to load extensions is:

```
 bool GLSLAPI initGLExtensions(void) {
     if (extensions_init) return true;
     extensions_init = true;

     GLenum err = glewInit();

     if (GLEW_OK != err) {
         cout << "Error:" << glewGetErrorString(err) << endl;
         extensions_init = false;
         return false;
     }

     cout << "OpenGL Vendor: " << (char*) glGetString(GL_VENDOR) << "\n";
     cout << "OpenGL Renderer: " << (char*) glGetString(GL_RENDERER) << "\n";
     cout << "OpenGL Version: " << (char*) glGetString(GL_VERSION) << "\n\n";

     checkGLSL();

     return true;
}
```

Where CheckGLSL looks for `glewGetExtension("GL_ARB_fragment_shader")` and `glewGetExtension("GL_ARB_vertex_shader")` to see if GLSL is supported.

P.S. If i remove glewExperimental, the code crashes on `glGenVertexArrays`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately GLEW is not really on par with current OpenGL development, especially if core context or explicit version profiles are involved. Only recently I had quite the same issue, also in conjunction with GLFW. Omitting to set the OpenGL version window hints did resolve the issue for me then. I.e. disable or remove those two calls:

```
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
```

Comment: Hmmm seems it's done, now i'm getting OpenGL 4.3.0, but another error showed up. I'l see if it's related and report back

Comment: Oh, it was a bug in glsllib... it got the wrong lenght :-0 thanks! :D

Comment: In my one project; I didn't use any third party library and had to setup all the API calls for OpenGL, create the windows class, set up the OpenGL context etc. In my current project I'm just being introduced to GLEW on a decent tutorial website and currently we are using OpenGL 3.3 Core. I haven't had any problems with it and I'm using VS2015. So this is something that is good to know now ahead of time before I decide to port to 4.4 or 4.5. If GLEW gives me problems; I'll go back to my other project. Anyway; thank you for the heads up in advance! :)

Comment: @FrancisCugler: GLEW should have caught up by now and to get a modern OpenGL context on implementations that do not support compatibility profile it may be necessary to set the version flags in addition to the core profile flag. Keep in mind that the answer is 3 years old and a few things (may) have changed.